# Preventing a setter being called twice in a Spring bean?

Tags: java, spring

I am being asked by a colleague to move our setters to constructors, in our Spring beans, since "the setter exposes a private variable that could be potentially changed after the construction phase in Spring".

While I can appreciate the sentiment, I am not sure this is the best approach? For this reason I am wondering whether there are ways in a Spring bean to prevent a setter from being called twice or whether we should have a check to see if we are before the post-construct phase?

My worry is the constructor uses indexes, rather than named properties. From a code maintenance point of view this is not very friendly.

Comment: _I am not sure this is the best approach_ Why not?

Comment: If you don't want a bean to be altered, then why do you keep these setters?

Comment: If a variable has to be set and never changed, then the best way is to mark it as `final` and set its value in a constructor.

Comment: Because in the Spring file we are applying a name of the property being set, rather than some anonymous index.

Comment: `<constructor-arg>` can be given an index, a type, and/or a name.

Comment: You can use `@Qualifier` or `@Named` to define which object should be used.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring supports field value insertion through reflection when you use `@Autowired` or `@Inject` on a private field. This way you do not have expose a setter nor use a constructor for dependency injection.

If you want the setter to be present you might consider defining your own annotation, defining a pointcut and creating an aspect that prevents method execution if the method has been called on the object at least once.

Personally I prefer having these fields populated through the constructor and marked as final. The amount of boiler-plate generated by this may sometimes be prohibitive when thinking about the readability of the code. To increase readability you may want to use `@Qualifier`or `@Named` annotations to further specify which object should satisfy the dependency when there are multiple possibilities.